# How to design table about such kind of request?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to use Cassandra as a message system's db. I keep all messages into a table that keeps all required data I will query later.
Now I have a request that I have to show a user's latest 10 chat room's lastest 100 messages. The chat room need order by the lasted access time.

I plan to create a table that let me get lasted 10 chatroom and ordered by their access time.

But I can't figure out how to design table. I currently do such request by creating a table with

user, chatroom, access_time. And using (user, chatroom) as primary key.

Then I update the access_time each time I received the message.
So I may have a table like this

```
user     chatroom     time
1           2          1005
2           1          1000
1           3          1003 
1           4          1004.
```

It's easy for me to get user 1's list as

```
1, 2, 1005,
1, 3, 1003,
1, 4, 1004.
```

The I reorder by myself and got

```
1, 3, 1003.
1, 4, 1004.
1, 2, 1005.
```

That what I need of the latest result. I need the [3, 4, 2] as the final result.
But I can't figure out a good way about how to do the sort part inside the Cassandra. 
Are there better design for the Table? 
In general, the chatroom should not be a big list. So the sorting time should not be a problem even if I sorted by myself.

Thank you~~

Eric

I did try the comment from Mandraenke. But My input is like:

```
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo2', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_4');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo3', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo2', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_4');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo3', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_3');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_4');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo4', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo5', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_3');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo7', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_4');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo6', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo8', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_5');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo9', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_7');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo2', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo3', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo5', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_3');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo6', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo7', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo2', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo3', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_3');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo7', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo6', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_5');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_8');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo2', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_3');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo3', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo5', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_3');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo6', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_4');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo7', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_3');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo2', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo3', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo6', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_3');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo6', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo2', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo2', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo2', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo2', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo2', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_3');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo4', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo6', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo2', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_3');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo1', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_3');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo2', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_2');
INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo3', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_1');
```

The result of my query:

```
select * from room_access where user='demo1';
```

will be

```
 user  | when                            | room
-------+---------------------------------+--------
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.886000+0000 | room_3
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.865000+0000 | room_1
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.850000+0000 | room_2
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.831000+0000 | room_2
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.738000+0000 | room_1
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.594000+0000 | room_2
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.556000+0000 | room_1
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.513000+0000 | room_1
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.456000+0000 | room_8
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.430000+0000 | room_1
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.404000+0000 | room_3
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.386000+0000 | room_1
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.202000+0000 | room_7
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.136000+0000 | room_3
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.088000+0000 | room_4
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.020000+0000 | room_2
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:26.964000+0000 | room_2
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:26.947000+0000 | room_1
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:14:47.267000+0000 | room_1
```

Dues to the access time modify frequently, the actual result will be more than thousands records (There are only 19 records in the sample.) but the actual result I want is

```
 user  | when                            | room
-------+---------------------------------+--------
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.886000+0000 | room_3
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.865000+0000 | room_1
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.850000+0000 | room_2
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.456000+0000 | room_8
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.202000+0000 | room_7
 demo1 | 2018-01-01 18:17:27.088000+0000 | room_4
```

It seems I still need additional filtering to get what I want.
So..Are there a simple way to do the filtering I want also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cassandra you almost always denormalize data to fit your queries. For your question just track access times for example as follows:

```
cqlsh:demo> create table room_access ( user text, when timestamp, room text, primary key (user, when) ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (when DESC);
```

The only purpose of that table is to track last access times per user. Note the clustering column and the descending order:

Lets insert some data:

```
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_a');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_b');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_c');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_d');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_e');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_f');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_g');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_h');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_i');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_j');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_k');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_l');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_b');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO room_access (user, when, room) VALUES ( 'demo', toTimeStamp(now()), 'room_a');
```

Now you can select the last ten rooms:

```
cqlsh:demo> SELECT room FROM room_access WHERE user='demo' limit 10;

 room
--------
 room_a
 room_b
 room_l
 room_k
 room_j
 room_i
 room_h
 room_g
 room_f
 room_e

(10 rows)
cqlsh:demo>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try this table before but the result is not I need in final, I still need to do filtering to get the final result. Are there some command that can filter the un-need data within the same query?

Comment: One idea would be tracking only the last access time for every room and user. See https://pastebin.com/xcDBBY3m - but that quick and dirty example is now unordered and you need to order by date. But you will only get a single row per room now.

Comment: Thanks, it's also the solution that I can figure out currently.